# DRM render node numbering

Tags: linux, drm

Why do DRM [render nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Manager#Render_nodes) in `/dev/dri/renderD<X>` start their numbering from 128 while the privileged interaces in `/dev/dri/card<X>` start at zero?

```
$ ls -al /dev/dri/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root        100 Nov 21 07:46 .
drwxr-xr-x  23 root root       6040 Nov 22 11:09 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root         80 Nov 21 07:46 by-path
crw-rw----+  1 root video  226,   0 Nov 21 07:46 card0
crw-rw----+  1 root render 226, 128 Nov 21 07:46 renderD128
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The privileged DRI interface came first, and a fixed major device number 226 was initially allocated for them [exclusively](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt).

As the ARM devices and the development of GPGPU compute devices proved that display mode-setting and rendering need to be accessible as separate devices, [render nodes were developed](https://dvdhrm.wordpress.com/2013/09/01/splitting-drm-and-kms-device-nodes/). It looks like the minor device numbers from 128 upwards was assigned for them, although I could not quickly find any documentation stating that explicitly.

The code that assigns the device numbers begins in the [`drm_dev_init()`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/gpu/drm/drm_drv.c?h=v6.0.9#n581) function in `drivers/gpu/drm/drm_drv.c` in the kernel source code. Starting at [line 631](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/gpu/drm/drm_drv.c?h=v6.0.9#n631) it calls the [`drm_minor_alloc`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/gpu/drm/drm_drv.c?h=v6.0.9#n112) function in the same file:

```
if (drm_core_check_feature(dev, DRIVER_RENDER)) {
    ret = drm_minor_alloc(dev, DRM_MINOR_RENDER);
    if (ret)
        goto err;
}

ret = drm_minor_alloc(dev, DRM_MINOR_PRIMARY);
if (ret)
    goto err;
```

It calls the [`idr_alloc()`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/lib/idr.c?h=v6.0.9#n59) in `lib/idr.c`:

```
r = idr_alloc(&drm_minors_idr,
          NULL,
          64 * type,
          64 * (type + 1),
          GFP_NOWAIT);
```

The parameters for `idr_alloc()` are:

```
* idr_alloc() - Allocate an ID.
* @idr: IDR handle.
* @ptr: Pointer to be associated with the new ID.
* @start: The minimum ID (inclusive).
* @end: The maximum ID (exclusive).
* @gfp: Memory allocation flags.
```

If the driver supports the `DRIVER_RENDER` feature and thus render nodes, `idr_alloc` gets called twice to first allocate the render node and then the primary node. Otherwise only the primary node is allocated.

The `DRM_MINOR_*` constants are defined in [`include/drm/drm_file.h`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/include/drm/drm_file.h#n52):

```
/* Note that the order of this enum is ABI (it determines
 * /dev/dri/renderD* numbers).
 */
enum drm_minor_type {
    DRM_MINOR_PRIMARY,
    DRM_MINOR_CONTROL,
    DRM_MINOR_RENDER,
};
```

Since this is an `enum`, `DRM_MINOR_PRIMARY` gets a value of 0, `DRM_MINOR_CONTROL` has a value of 1 and `DRM_MINOR_RENDER` 2 respectively.

This works out to allocating minor device numbers in range 0 <= x < 64 to primary interface nodes, 64 <= x < 128 to DRM_MINOR_CONTROL nodes (whatever they might be... seems currently unused in 6.0.x kernels?) and 128 <= x < 192 to DRM_MINOR_RENDER nodes.

The sysfs name for the device is then assigned in [`drivers/gpu/drm/drm_sysfs.c`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/gpu/drm/drm_sysfs.c#n468) in function `drm_sysfs_minor_alloc()`, simply using the minor device number as part of the name:

```
if (minor->type == DRM_MINOR_RENDER)
    minor_str = "renderD%d";
else
    minor_str = "card%d";

[...]

r = dev_set_name(kdev, minor_str, minor->index);
```

And unless `udev` rules are used to modify the default device name, the sysfs name becomes the name of the device node too.

So basically, it's because nobody has so far bothered to add a condition clause that would subtract 128 from the minor device node number when assigning the default device name if it is a render node.

Also, note that [this DRM development blog article from 2013](https://dvdhrm.wordpress.com/2013/09/01/splitting-drm-and-kms-device-nodes/) says:

> It’s also important to know that render-nodes are **not** bound to a specific card. While internally it’s created by the same driver as the legacy node, user-space should never assume any connection between a render-node and a legacy/mode-setting node. Instead, if user-space requires hardware-acceleration, it should open **any** node and use it.
>
> [...]
>
> Questions like “how do I find the render-node for a given card?” don’t make any sense. Yes, driver-specific user-space can figure out whether and which render-node was created by which driver, but driver-unspecific user-space should never do that!

Given that intent, the choice of deliberately starting the numbering of render nodes from 128 (to break the potentially false assumption that `card0` and `renderD0` would always refer to the same card) might make sense.

Comment: wow. Thanks for the deep dive! It is good to know that it is not relic from RIVA128 or something.